# How to force cell dimensions in a tblr from tabularray

Tags: tables, formatting, tabularray

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
  hlines,
  vlines,
  rows={15mm},
  columns={15mm},
}
a & bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb \\
c & d \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, the cells are definitely not 15 mm x 15 mm. What are my options to force those cell dimensions?

Comment: Maybe   rowsep=0pt,
  colsep=0pt ?  It has a different problem though

Comment: Although how do you expect to fit that long text into that small cell...?

Comment: Can you show with some sketch, what result you expect from your MWE. If your cell are empty, their sizes are 15mm x 15mm. However, `tabularray` expect, that cell content should not protrude bottom of cell, so it extend cell high accordingly. So far, as I know, you are the first, who require that text must protrude bottom of cells ...

Comment: If you want to shrink text in cells in `tabularray`, see this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/648978/106776

Comment: I'm used to CSS and while elements in HTML usually also adjust to their content, I can also set fixed dimensions and decide what to do with overflowing content: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playdemo.asp?filename=playcss_overflow